# Error while running the build.xml usint ANT Build in eclipse/junit

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, ant, junit

I am new to webdriver, I just want to execute my script and generate the test result using ANT Build in selenium/Junit. When I try to run the script I am getting the following error:

> ${ECLIPSE_HOME}\plugins does not exist.

How can I solve this?

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Script\build.xml
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
     [echo] Script: C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Script\build.xml
build:
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Script\bin
cleanall:
clean:
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Script\bin
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
     [echo] Script: C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\Script\build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Script\bin
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
    [javac] 1 warning
build-refprojects:
init-eclipse-compiler:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\Script\build.xml:43: C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\Script\${ECLIPSE_HOME}\plugins does not exist.

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 3):

{ECLIPSE_HOME} is a property that ant is looking for and has not been defined.  You can either define this property at the top of your build.xml:

```
<property
    name="ECLIPSE_HOME"
    location="C:\Program Files\eclipse" />
```

Or you can add the property to your PATH under Environment Variables

Or if your build.xml references a project.properties or ant.properties file you can add this line:

```
ECLIPSE_HOME=C:\Program Files\eclipse
```

Please note "C:\Program Files\eclipse" was just an example, place your real directory path to your Eclipse on your machine.

Comment: Thank for the reply @ripple.....after changing the code... and getting a new error like tis........C:\Users\xxxxxxx\workspace\Script\build.xml:41: Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter

Comment: thanks for the replay and itz working fine now but am getting a new error like...........workspace\Script\build.xml:41: Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter